# Loading A PyQt5 UI Via A Class

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside, pyside2

I'm currently trying to update my PySide code using PyQt5. And I have a class called "loader.py" that used to use "QUiLoader" from "PySide.QtUiTools", but as far as I know in PyQt5 this module has been changed by "uic".

So the problem here is that I changed my "QUiLoader" import from "uic" but I always get this error:

`ui_loader.py", line 4, in <module> class UiLoader(uic): TypeError: module() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)`

**Original Code in Pyside**

Here is where I got the [code](https://robonobodojo.wordpress.com/2017/10/03/loading-a-pyside-ui-via-a-class/) for my PySide app

**Code in PyQt5**

*ui_loader.py*

```
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import QMetaObject

class UiLoader(uic):
    def __init__(self, base_instance):
        uic.__init__(self, base_instance)
        self.base_instance = base_instance

    def createWidget(self, class_name, parent=None, name=''):
        if parent is None and self.base_instance:
            return self.base_instance
        else:
            # create a new widget for child widgets
            widget = uic.createWidget(self, class_name, parent, name)
            if self.base_instance:
                setattr(self.base_instance, name, widget)
            return widget

def load_ui(ui_file, base_instance=None):
    loader = UiLoader(base_instance)
    widget = loader.load(ui_file)
    QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(widget)
    return widget
```

*main.py*

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from ui_loader import load_ui
import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        load_ui('my_interface.ui', self)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have also tried to used submethod of the class and refactoring all the code but it was useless.

Comment: You don't need to do that, as `uic.loadUi` already does it natively. Just use `uic.loadUi('path/to/file.ui', self)`

Comment: @musicamante So you mean that I dont need my "UiLoader" class and I can just leave my load_ui fuction changed as :
`def load_ui(ui_file, base_instance=None):
    widget = uic.loadUi(ui_file, base_instance)
    QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(widget)
    return widget`
right?

Comment: No, I mean that you don't need **any of that** at all any more: just import uic and call `loadUi` instead of your `load_ui` (which is now useless, so you can completely remove that custom module).

Answer (score 0):

You can actually load the ui using uic and then just inherit that ui into a class then self.setupUI()

```
ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType("main_window.ui")

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
```

Another way as musicamante is suggesting would be like this:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("main_window.ui", self)
```

Comment: While this works, it's not necessary, as `loadUi` already does what the OP was doing with the custom function, so it also minimizes changes to their code.

Comment: I edited the answer to include the method you are referring to. I have a separate file where I manage the paths to a bunch of UI files so for me I like to have the reference of the ui_MainWindow established in a different file and I just do self.setupUI so I don't need to keep track of the file name and directory of the ui's within the class, but you are right your solution is less code.

Comment: I can completely understand your point of view, as I often did that on my own. But this is a *common knowledge* place. We have to try to stick to conventions (no matter how strange or, even, wrong they might be). It's a meta-language, and while we might try to extend it (by extending our answers to complex matters), we should also try to make any possible effort to make any answer as "right" as possible. I've plenty of scripts, hacks and mods in my computers, but I'm aware that I cannot use those anywhere, especially here. The context is fundamental, even if not always efficient.